# Why must one say "C'est d'écouter" instead of "C'est écouter"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, infinitif

While speaking to a French person, I said

> La chose la plus difficile pour moi avec le français, c'est écouter

But he corrected me to say

> C'est **D'** écouter

Why is this? And why is it necessary to add "D'" after c'est and before écouter? Is there a rule for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*C'est écouter* is not completely incorrect although grammarians tell that when the real subject (*écouter*) is an infinitive, it is introduced by *de*. The [oqlf](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4217) states :

> L'infinitif en fonction attribut est précédé de la préposition **de**
> lorsque le sujet n'est pas un autre verbe à l'infinitif et qu'il est
> repris par une expression comme c'est ou ce serait.

Dropping *de* is however common at least in lazy/spoken French, especially because there is no adjective before the infinitive.

*De* is often not considered to be a preposition but seen as a marker of the infinitive, just like "to" in English (to listen). It can also be interpreted to mean *le fait de*:

> La chose la plus difficile pour moi avec le français, c'est le fait d'écouter.

*De* is mandatory when used in this pattern:

> *c'est* + adjective + *de* + infinitive, e.g.:
>
> *C'est difficile [pour moi] d'écouter le français.*